# django-admin returns - zsh: [PATH] no such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, django, admin

I read through similar posts and learned the Path may be an issue. When I request my path I get the following:

(env) Josevv@Eye-C-You env % echo $PATH
/Users/Shared/codeproj/env/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

I see a lot of repetition here. Does anything seem extraordinary here?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by uninstalling and re-installing django